# create file of user defined input

Tags: c++

I have two functions `add_account` and `is_account_exists`, I am  trying to create the code,  to create file if it does not exists already.

But the problem is taking input of filename as shown in code as Problem 1

Here's my code what i've tried

```
void add_account()
{

    std::string name,account;
    cout<<"Enter name of account : ";
    std::getline(std::cin,name);

    cout<<endl<<name<<endl;   //Problem 1 , here 'name' is not displaying
    string ext=".txt";
    account=name.append(ext);
    cout<<account;             

    if(is_account_exists(account)==0){
        ofstream outfile(account.c_str());
        cout<<"Account created!";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Account already exists!";
    }
}


 bool is_account_exists(const string& name) {
    ifstream f(name.c_str());
    if (f.good()) {
        f.close();
        return true;
    } else {
       f.close();
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic of determining if the account exists. In any case, it's not necessary to explicitly close the file.

Comment: @JohnOdom you should always prefer `getline` over `cin`. also  `is_account_exists` should be `does_account_exist`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried entering your program, with some slight which involve me putting it in a main() and my code is thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    string name, account;
    cout << "Enter the name of the account: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << endl << "Name is set to " << name << endl;
    string ext = ".txt";
    account = name.append(ext);
    cout << "Account is set to: " << account << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I know I've not done it in an add account like you have done, but I've popped this in a main as I wanted to see what would happen if I typed in pretty much exactly what you did in the method, and it appears to run fine.

I was wondering if you got any errors or have you forgotten an include or something?  Did the program prompt you for an input when you called the function?

So in your main() for example, do you have a call to add_account()?

I'm sorry to ask another question within an answer, but at first glance I can see nothing wrong with your code.

**Edit**

Just had another look at your code, and your cout doesn't have a std:: in front of it the same way that you have before string and cin, check that too.  Sorry I missed that one...

Comment: That not help if the filename has spaces. Example "a perfect valid filename.txt"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `name` is being displayed but don't contains what you expect. After a very simple test I've verified that there is no reason for you code to fail getting the user input to `name` (Dispate of the inconsistences using `std::cin`, `std::string` and `cout` and `endl` --without std::--).

This is the test:

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
std::cout << name << std::endl;
```

and works perfectly.

So a couple of things to check:

1. After the program prompts for the filename, be sure you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> only once.
2. Try to debug your code and see what does really contain `name`.